# What does it mean to say a functor is represented by $(X,a)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

I have a question about Yoneda lemma etc. In class, we proved the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** Let $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \text{Sets}$ be a functor. There is a bijection between the natural transformations from $h^{X}$
>   to $F$ and the elements of $F(X)$.
>
> Surjectivity is shown as: let $a \in F(X)$. We prove there exists some
>   natural transformation $\eta: h^{X} \rightarrow F$ sending $1_{X}$ in
>   $h^{X} (X)$ to $a$. Let $Y$ be any object in $\mathcal{C}$ and define
>   $$ \eta_{Y} : h^{X} (Y) \rightarrow F(Y): f \mapsto F(f)(a). $$

I understand the proof, but there is a remark following the proof, saying:

> **Remark:** From the proof of Yoneda lemma, it is easy to see that if $F$ is a representable functor, i.e. it is naturally isomorphic to
>   some $h^{X}$, then there is no need to write down a natural
>   isomorphism $\eta: h^{X} \rightarrow F$ explicitly. It is determined
>   by $a : = \eta_{X} (1_X).$ So we will often say $F$ is represented by
>   $(X,a)$ instead.

I'm not sure if I understand this remark. Is the $a$ in the $(X,a)$ unique? Let's say I have the following problem:

**problem:** Consider the forgetful functor. Show that $\text{Forget}: Ab \rightarrow \text{Sets}$ is represented by $(\mathbb{Z}, 1)$. Why? What is the natural equivalence?

**Attempt:** I would define a natural transformation $\eta: h^{\mathbb{Z}} \rightarrow \text{Forget}.$ Then for any $m \in \text{Forget}(\mathbb{Z})$ and any $G \in \text{Ob}(Ab)$ (this is an abelian group) I would define $$\eta_G : h^{\mathbb{Z}} (G) \rightarrow \text{Forget} (G): f \mapsto \text{Forget}(f)(m) = f(m). $$ Then I easily see that $\eta_{\mathbb{Z}} (1_{\mathbb{Z}}) = m. $

So I would say that the forgetful functor can be represented by  $(\mathbb{Z}, m)$ where $m$ is any integer.

My question is: what is the $a$ in $(X,a)$? Is this supposed to be a unique element? And how does one in general show that a functor is representable on certain categories?

Answer (score 1):

The Yoneda Lemma asserts that to each natural transformation $\eta: h^{X} \rightarrow F$, there corresponds a unique element, $a$, of $F(X)$, via the natural bijection $\theta:\eta\mapsto a:=\eta_X(1_X).$ Now, if $\eta$ *happens* to be an isomorphism; that is, if $F$ is representable, then it is determined by $a$ because $\eta=\theta^{-1}(a).$

Comment: I see. How would I show for example that $\text{Forget} : \text{Field} \rightarrow \text{Sets}$ is not representable? Do I just pick some $X$, say $X = \mathbb{Z}_2$, and then show that $\eta: h^{\mathbb{Z}_2} \rightarrow \text{Forget}$ is not an isomorphism for all fields?

Comment: @Kamil No. A representation of $F$ is a *pair* of an object $X$ and a natural isomorphism $\theta:h^X\to F$ or, as is the purpose of the remark, a pair $X$ and an element of $FX$ (which, by the way, is often referred to as the universal element). What you describe would only show that $(\mathbb Z_2,\eta)$ isn't a representation. It could still be the case that $(\mathbb Z_2,\alpha)$ is a representation or that $(k,\beta)$ is. To show that a functor isn't representable, you need to show that there is *no* object *and* natural isomorphism/universal element that represents it.